# Java и Pascal. Цикл while и repeat ... until

Tags: java, pascal, while

В языке Паскаль есть операторы `repeat ... until`. Зачем нужно было их создавать, если есть цикл `while`? И если есть разница, то почему в Java нет этих операторов?

Comment: Минусы уберите, за что они мне?

Comment: в java аналогом `repeat...untill` является `do...while`, что в свою очередь так же отличается от просто `while`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь (не часто используется) в Java `do { ... } while(...);`  Разница с паскакалевским репитом - условие притивоположное. т.е. в паскакале выход при true, в java при false. Так что все тоже самое есть и там и тут со своими нюансами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница есть.

В цикле `while` условие проверяется **до** выполнения тела цикла, а в цикле `repeat` **после**.

В Java этих операторов нет по той простой причине, что в основу Java положен C-подобный (а не Pascal-подобный) синтаксис.
В нем цикл с предусловием записывается как `while (CONDITION) ...`, а цикл с постусловием как `do { ... } while (CONDITION);`

Маленькая историческая справка:
[pascal](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) появился в 1970 году
[C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) появился в 1972 году
[Java](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) появился в 1995 году

Comment: Как же я сразу не догадался. Разница есть )

Answer (score 4):

Разница существенна - цикл с пост-условием (`repeat .. until`) в любом случае выполнится как минимум 1 раз, вне зависимости от того, какое условие выхода заложено в цикл.

Безусловно, этого же эффекта можно добиться и в цикле с пред-условием (`while`), который может не выполниться ни одного раза, соответствующим образом модифицировав используемые в сравнении данные. Но зачем?

Иногда в реализуемой логике на языке Pascal или Delphi циклы с пост-условием бывают очень полезны.

Comment: Точно так же, как и в Java они бывают полезны. Паскаль в этом смысле ничем не отличается от Java.

Comment: @m.vokhm да. Ответ был написан до появления комментариев о наличии сходного вида цикла в java. А так как я не владею java - не счел правильным писать о том, чего не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Это всего лишь личные предпочтения создателя языка Pascal  Никласа Вирта, и спросить об этом стоило бы у него (собственно, на этом можно бы и закончить). 
Но тут в голову приходят следующие довольно очевидные соображения. Паскаль был задуман как язык для обучения программированию (хотя в итоге и мутировал в нечто большее), и, вероятно, потому для вящей наглядности Вирт использовал разные ключевые слова для разных циклов чтобы начинающий программист уж точно не перепутал цикл с предусловием и цикл с постусловием. Вероятно из тех же соображений в Паскале используются относительно громоздкие `begin...end` вместо компактных, но не очень понятных начинающему фигурных скобок.

Java же напротив изначально создавался как язык для взрослых дяденек, и необходимости вводить два лишних ключевых слова не было